# Using regex for repeating text in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have links like this:

```
https://d2ynliea65eb6o.cloudfront.net/6100052500-STXMLOPEN/sub_1.m3u8
https://d2ynliea65eb6o.cloudfront.net/6100052499-STXMLOPEN/sub_1.m3u8
https://d2ynliea65eb6o.cloudfront.net/6100052498-STXMLOPEN/sub_1.m3u8
```

How can I use a regex in Notepad++ to make them like this:

```
https://d2ynliea65eb6o.cloudfront.net/6100052500-STXMLOPEN/6100052500-STXMLOPENsub_1.m3u8
https://d2ynliea65eb6o.cloudfront.net/6100052499-STXMLOPEN/6100052499-STXMLOPENsub_1.m3u8
https://d2ynliea65eb6o.cloudfront.net/6100052498-STXMLOPEN/6100052498-STXMLOPENsub_1.m3u8
```

I want to repeat what is between `net/` and `/sub` for each link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to repeat the characters before the last `/`.

You may try this regex:

- Regex

```
([^/\n]+)/(?=[^/\n]+$)
```

- Substitution

```
$1/$1
```

```
([^/\n]+)       // any consecutive non-slash and non-linebreak characters, and capture them in group 1
/               // a slash
(?=[^/\n]+$)    // lookahead, there must be non-slash and non-linebreak characters followed by the end of a line ahead
```

Check the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/ulvGbW/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to actually search for and repeat what's in between "net/" and "/sub" and repeat that then you can use:

```
 (net/(.*?))/sub
```

replace with:

```
 $1/$2sub
```

the second () ie  (.*?) will create group $2 which will contain the variable text that occurs between net/  and /sub

the first (), which DOES NOT contain the /sub will contain the text up to, but not including the "/sub" text and put it into $1. If you want to include the "/sub" you would put the ")" on the right side of "/sub".

then  $1/$2sub will be the concatenation of $1  with a "/" then $2 then "sub"  then the remainder of the text